# Download file in Laravel from AWS S3(non public bucket)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to save all my files in the bucket but having difficulties with download.
My code is:

```
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
        $request->file, now()->addMinutes(10)
    );
    return Storage::disk('s3')->download($url);
```

Full file path stored in `$request->file`

Example path: `https://bucket_name.privacy_region_info/folder_inside_bucket/cTymyY2gzakfczO3j3H2TtbJX4eeRW4Uj073CZUW`

I am getting the fallowing https://prnt.sc/1ip4g77

Did I not understand the purpose od generating temporaryUrl? How can I download files from S3 non public bucket?

*BTW I am using Laravel 8 and league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 1.0.29.*

Comment: Check out your AWS permissions,   note the "anyone can create one, but for it to be available it needs to be created by someone that has permission" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: 1) Does the AWS user, have correct permissions assigned to it, to be able to download from the private bucket? The user will need explicit permission assign to it. This could be done via an IAM policy in AWS

Comment: @edd-smith I think this may be the case. My permission https://prnt.sc/1j0m5xh. I'll have to ask my admins for Read permissions as well. Thank you both for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have shown suggests your user does not have the correct permissions, or that the file does not exist.

If you are sure the file exists, i would suspect a permissions issue.

In AWS IAM, make sure the user has a policy attached to it that grants the correct permissions.

In this case from the comments, i can see the user only has "Write" permissions. You will need explicit "Read" permissions too.

Comment: I solved the problem with the fallowing:  `if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists('/'.$request->file)){             return Storage::disk('s3')->download('/'.$request->file,'name' );  } ` where `$request->file` is just `foldername/file_name_with_extencion` and not full path. But I am encountering another problem now. Instead of downloading the file I can only see it in Preview in my inspect element. I try adding header `'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment;'` but same result.  Any thoughts on how I can solve this?